# How to iterate a list, to get combination of all next values

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, combinations, sequence

Problem: Obtain the combination of all next values of the array.

Explanation: All the values should be formed by contiguous elements in the array.

Posible solution(not optimal):

```
l_number= list("24256")
result= []
while l_number:
    n = "" 
    for x in l_number:
        n += x
        result.append(str(n))
    
    l_number.pop(0)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['2', '24', '242', '2425', '24256', '4', '42', '425', '4256', '2', '25', '256', '5', '56', '6']
```

I got this, but it is not very efficient.

Is there any optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be outputting all contiguous sublists, the size of the output will be O(N^2) where N is the length of the list, and time complexity will be at least quadratic no matter what (You could achieve linear space complexity by using a generator). Here is one way to compute all contiguous substrings with a list comprehension:

```
s = "24256"
n = len(s)
res = [s[i:j] for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,n+1)]
print(res)
# ['2', '24', '242', '2425', '24256', '4', '42', '425', '4256', '2', '25', '256', '5', '56', '6']
```

As an aside, it is usually undesirable to build up lists with `str += ...` since a new copy of `str` is created on each iteration. One workaround is to create a list of components and call `.join` once all components have been found.

Comment: Just a small correction, should change `res = (s[i:j] for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,n+1))` to make it as a generator.  :-)

Comment: Good point, my original statement was possibly misleading. I used a list comprehension instead of a generator to match the desired output. I clarified the statement to make this issue more clear.